# BIRT Designer select statment inside CASE THEN

Tags: sql, database, select, db2, birt

I have a problem in BIRT Designer 4.3.1, where I have SQL Query inside my script.

```
sqlText = " SELECT MXZINVTRANS.ORGID, MXZINVTRANS.ITEMSETID, MXZINVTRANS.SITEID, MXZINVTRANS.TRANSDATE, MXZINVTRANS.STORELOC, MXZINVTRANS.STORELOC_DESCRIPTION,  "
+ "         MXZINVTRANS.ACTUALDATE, MXZINVTRANS.TOSTORELOC, MXZINVTRANS.MAXTAB, MXZINVTRANS.TRANSGROUP, MXZINVTRANS.DOCUMENT,  "
+ "         MXZINVTRANS.REFDOC, MXZINVTRANS.ITEMNUM, MXZINVTRANS.CONDITIONCODE, MXZINVTRANS.ITEM_DESCRIPTION, MXZINVTRANS.COMMODITYGROUP,  "
+ "         MXZINVTRANS.COMMODITYGROUP_DESCRIPTION, MXZINVTRANS.ISSUEUNIT, MXZINVTRANS.TRANSTYPE, MXZINVTRANS.TRANSTYPE_DESCRIPTION, MXZINVTRANS.QUANTITY,  "
+ "         MXZINVTRANS.MAXIMOQUANTITY, MXZINVTRANS.UNITCOST, MXZINVTRANS.LINECOST, MXZINVTRANS.FINPER, MXZINVTRANS.CURBALBEFORE,  "
+ "         MXZINVTRANS.CURBALAFTER, MXZINVTRANS.COSTCENTER, MXZINVTRANS.COSTCENTER2, MXZINVTRANS.SAPUNITCOST, MXZINVTRANS.SAPPRICEUNIT,  "
+ "         MXZINVTRANS.SAPLINECOST, MXZINVTRANS.SAPTRANSID, "
//+ "            (case MXZINVTRANS.TRANSTYPE  "
//+ "              WHEN 'RECEIPT' THEN 'Prejem' "
//+ "              WHEN 'RETURN' THEN 'Vrač. na skl.' "
//+ "              WHEN 'ISSUE' THEN 'TOREK' "
//+ "              WHEN 'TRANSFER' THEN 'Izd. med skl.' "
//+ "              WHEN 'INSERTITEM' THEN 'Insertitem_??' "
//+ "              WHEN 'VOIDRECEIPT' THEN 'Voidreceipt_??' "
//+ "              WHEN 'SHIPTRANSFER' THEN 'shiptransfer_??' "
//+ "              WHEN 'SHIPCANCEL' THEN 'shipcancel_??' "
//+ "              WHEN 'SHIPRECEIPT' THEN 'shipreceipts_??' "
//+ "           end) as tip_trans,  "
+ "          (case MXZINVTRANS.TRANSTYPE_DESCRIPTION  "
+ "             WHEN 'Prejem pošiljke'  THEN (select description from locations where locations.location=MXZINVTRANS.tostoreloc and locations.siteid=MXZINVTRANS.SITEID) "
+ "             WHEN 'Prenos pošiljke'  THEN (select description from locations where locations.location=MXZINVTRANS.tostoreloc and locations.siteid=MXZINVTRANS.SITEID) "
+ "             WHEN 'Ident prejema'    THEN (select distinct VENDOR from PO where PO.PONUM=left(MXZINVTRANS.REFDOC, LOCATE('-',MXZINVTRANS.REFDOC)-1)) "
//+ "               WHEN 'Ident vračila' THEN (select distinct NAME from COMPANIES where COMPANIES.COMPANY=(select distinct VENDOR from PO where PO.PONUM=left(MXZINVTRANS.REFDOC, LOCATE('-',MXZINVTRANS.REFDOC)-1) and PO.SITEID=MXZINVTRANS.SITEID)) "
+ "             end) as opis_storeloc  "
//+ " (select description from locations where locations.location=MXZINVTRANS.tostoreloc and locations.siteid=MXZINVTRANS.SITEID) as opis_storeloc "

+ " FROM MXZINVTRANS "
// Include the Maximo where clause
//+ " where " + params["where"]

//+ " and invbalances.itemnum = '2000049451' "
//+ " and invbalances.itemnum like '2000000%' "
+ " where 1=1 "

+ " and(( trunc(MXZINVTRANS.TRANSDATE) ) <=  TO_DATE ('" + params["datum_do"] + "','YYYY-MM-DD') and ( trunc(MXZINVTRANS.TRANSDATE) ) >=  TO_DATE ('" + params["datum_od"] + "','YYYY-MM-DD'))"

+ storeroomwhere
+ blagskupinawhere
+ itemwhere
+ tipwhere


//+ " and invbalances.itemnum ='2000049451' "
//+ " and  siteid='6000'"
//+ " order by po.ponum " 
;

maximoDataSet.setQuery(sqlText);
```

and here is may main problem:

```
+ " WHEN 'Ident prejema'    THEN (select distinct VENDOR from PO where PO.PONUM=left(MXZINVTRANS.REFDOC, LOCATE('-',MXZINVTRANS.REFDOC)-1)) "
```

First to explain, REFODC is value something like this 4500038258-R2-120, with LEFT I get this number 4500038258 and I looked after this in table PO where is equal to PONUM, and then I print VENDOR as number 114263 for example.

The problem is here, that here I have errors, but if I write directly instead MXZINVTRANS.REFDOC number 4500038258 there are non errors. Also if print only this substring of REFDOC value, I get correct substring at report and without errors, so the problem is probably here?

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHYVD.png)

Comment: You should add the actual error message to your question. Furthermore, I don't know if this is possible in DB2, but with Oracle you could either trace your session or the network traffic. This would show you the exact query text. You could also dump the generated SQL statement to a text file. I'm pretty sure that something is wrong with either the gerneated statement or with the bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already dumped the generated SQL statement and tested it successfully outside of BIRT, keep in mind that for every dataset parameter you need a corresponding bind variable occurence in your statement.

For example, if your dataset has *two* dataset parameters, you need exactly *two* bind variables (syntax is DB-dependent, the JDBC standard `?` should workf for every DB.

If these numbers do not match, this will result in errors.

Answer (score 0):

I solved something. Its working, but I have problem below:

```
+ " case " 
+ " WHEN MXZINVTRANS.TOSTORELOC IS NULL "

    + " THEN case WHEN MXZINVTRANS.TRANSTYPE_DESCRIPTION='Izdaja' "
        + " THEN case WHEN MXZINVTRANS.DOCUMENT LIKE '%-%' "
            + " THEN left(MXZINVTRANS.DOCUMENT, LOCATE('-',MXZINVTRANS.DOCUMENT)-1) "
            + " ELSE MXZINVTRANS.DOCUMENT "
        + " END "
    + " END "

    + " THEN case WHEN MXZINVTRANS.TRANSTYPE_DESCRIPTION='Ident prejema' "
        + " THEN (select distinct VENDOR from PO where PO.PONUM=MXZINVTRANS.DOCUMENT) "
    + " END "
    
+ " ELSE "
+ " MXZINVTRANS.TOSTORELOC "
+ " END "
+ " AS TOSTORELOC"
```

When I use it like this there are errors, when I use just code in blue circle without code in red circle that working.

```
+ " case " 
+ " WHEN MXZINVTRANS.TOSTORELOC IS NULL "

    + " THEN case WHEN MXZINVTRANS.TRANSTYPE_DESCRIPTION='Izdaja' "
        + " THEN case WHEN MXZINVTRANS.DOCUMENT LIKE '%-%' "
            + " THEN left(MXZINVTRANS.DOCUMENT, LOCATE('-',MXZINVTRANS.DOCUMENT)-1) "
            + " ELSE MXZINVTRANS.DOCUMENT "
        + " END "
    + " END "
    
+ " ELSE "
+ " MXZINVTRANS.TOSTORELOC "
+ " END "
+ " AS TOSTORELOC"
```

And If I use code in red circle without code in blue circle that working too.

```
+ " case " 
+ " WHEN MXZINVTRANS.TOSTORELOC IS NULL "
    + " THEN case WHEN MXZINVTRANS.TRANSTYPE_DESCRIPTION='Ident prejema' "
        + " THEN (select distinct VENDOR from PO where PO.PONUM=MXZINVTRANS.DOCUMENT) "
    + " END "
    
+ " ELSE "
+ " MXZINVTRANS.TOSTORELOC "
+ " END "
+ " AS TOSTORELOC"
```

Any suggestions why is not working together?

Answer (score 0):

I trid in SQuirrel, but I dont understand why is this syntax error?

This not working:

```
+ " (case WHEN MXZINVTRANS.TOSTORELOC IS NULL "


    + " THEN case WHEN MXZINVTRANS.TRANSTYPE_DESCRIPTION='Ident prejema' "
        + " THEN (select distinct VENDOR from PO where PO.PONUM=MXZINVTRANS.DOCUMENT) "
    + " END "
    
    + " THEN case WHEN MXZINVTRANS.TRANSTYPE_DESCRIPTION='Ident vračila' "
        + " THEN (select distinct VENDOR from PO where PO.PONUM=MXZINVTRANS.DOCUMENT) "
    + " END "
    
    
+ " ELSE "
+ " MXZINVTRANS.TOSTORELOC "
+ " END) "
+ " AS TOSTORELOC"
```

And this is working:

```
+ " (case WHEN MXZINVTRANS.TOSTORELOC IS NULL "


    + " THEN case WHEN MXZINVTRANS.TRANSTYPE_DESCRIPTION='Ident prejema' OR MXZINVTRANS.TRANSTYPE_DESCRIPTION='Ident vračila' "
        + " THEN (select distinct VENDOR from PO where PO.PONUM=MXZINVTRANS.DOCUMENT) "
    + " END "
    
    
+ " ELSE "
+ " MXZINVTRANS.TOSTORELOC "
+ " END) "
+ " AS TOSTORELOC"
```